# Magento: after payment user is logged out and redirect to empty shoppingcart

Tags: magento, redirect, payment, magento-1.8

When a user successfully finished the payment process. We use Ogone as payment collector. After the payment when the user is redirected to the magento store. The user is logged out and the only thing he sees is a empty shoppingcart and not the succes page.

Who knows a fix?

Comment: Looks like in Ogone you can set the url the user is returned to `Please enter a URL in the 'URL of the merchant's post-payment page' field(s).`  Sounds to me like you've got it set it to the cart which will of course be empty, change it to the order success url.

Comment: We did this, but the problem is still there. Also the user shouldn't be logged out, right?

Comment: I believe this is oGone misconfiguration. Ensure you double check the settings including website/store scope for it and follow documentation/check if they have a sandbox to test against. Then flush cache to ensure the configuration is populated. Always flush cache.